# WPF TreeView using VirtualizingStackPanel: bring item into view programmatically

Tags: wpf, treeview

I'm using a WPF `TreeView` with virtualization enabled:

```xml
VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" 
VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"
```

I would like to select an item which is not visible. E.g. having a tree like this

```
0 
1 
3 --
   - 3.1
   - 3.2
   - ...
   - 3.500
   - ...
   - 3.1000
4 
5
```

I would like to select entry 3.500. I've read a lot of [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325/how-can-i-remove-a-specific-item-from-an-array) already but I got nothing to work. The only thing that's working is this:

```cs
VirtualizingPanel panel = VisualHelper.FindVisualChild<VirtualizingPanel>( this.treeView );   
panel.BringIndexIntoViewPublic( indexOfItem );
```

Unfortunately this only seems to work with non hierarchical controls. In my example above the max index is 5 which scrolls to the end of the list (making Item "5" visible).
But what if I want to scroll to an item which is in the *child* of another item? Like item 3.500? `BringIndexIntoViewPublic` is not working anymore.
Calls to `someTreeViewItem.BringIntoView()` are also not working - I guess because the items container was not build as its off-screen.
Is there another way to use `VirtualizingStackPanel` *and* programmatically select an item which is not in view?

Answer (score -1):

You need to bring the item to be selected into view before you can actually select it.

There is a tutorial in the official docs that explains how to find a `TreeViewItem` in a virtualized `TreeView`:

[How to: Find a TreeViewItem in a TreeView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/how-to-find-a-treeviewitem-in-a-treeview?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077)

You need to expand the container:

```
if (container is TreeViewItem && !((TreeViewItem)container).IsExpanded)
{
    container.SetValue(TreeViewItem.IsExpandedProperty, true);
}
```

...and then try to generate the ItemsPresenter and the ItemsPanel by calling ApplyTemplate:

```
container.ApplyTemplate();
ItemsPresenter itemsPresenter =
    (ItemsPresenter)container.Template.FindName("ItemsHost", container);
if (itemsPresenter != null)
{
    itemsPresenter.ApplyTemplate();
}
...
```